# Yii ошибка 400, при обращении к внешнему Action

Tags: yii, action

Не могу подключить *экшн*. при обращении к `/post/image` выдает ошибку 400.

Контроллер:

```
public function actions()
{
    return array(
        'image' => 'application.controllers.Actions.imAction',
    );
}
```

сам экшн

```
class imAction extends CAction
{
    public function run($id)
    {
        echo $id;
    }
}
```

Делал по [документации](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/ru/basics.controller#sec-4).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В вашем методе run() для этого action значение $id по умолчанию не указано. Из URL вида /post/image ID не извлекается. Поэтому два решения проблемы:

1. Используйте URL вида /post/image/1 где 1 это ID изображения, например.
2. Используете код вида:

```
 
   class imAction extends CAction
    {
        public function run($id = null)
        {
            if (is_null($id)){
                // Находим изображение по умолчанию, например первое.
                $image = Image::model()->find();
            } else {
                $image = Image::model()->findByPk($id);
            }
            $this->render('view', compact('image'));
        }
    }
```

Ну и на вторую версию Yii переходить уже можно свободно.

Comment: Да, большое спасибо! Забыл отписать. На вторую версию обязательно перейду!